# Are nested copybooks allowed in COBOL?

Tags: cobol

I know that many COBOL compilers do allow nested copybooks (with a different depth), but I did not found any "official" rule.
Questions:

1. Is there any COBOL standard explicit allowing or forbidding nested copybooks?
2. Is there any COBOL compiler not allowing nested copybooks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard permits nested copybooks, but does not allow any `COPY` statements to be mentioned in or be manipulated by the `REPLACING` clause. From the standard, `COPY` statement, general rules 11 to 14 (COBOL 2014 7.2.2.3, identical in COBOL 2002 7.1.2.3):

> 11. If the `REPLACING` phrase is specified, the library text shall not contain a `COPY` statement.
> 12. ...
> 13. If the `REPLACING` phrase is not specified, the library text may contain a `COPY` statement that does not include a `REPLACING` phrase. The implementation shall support nesting of at least 5 levels, including the first `COPY` statement in the sequence. The library text being copied shall not cause the processing of a `COPY` statement that directly or indirectly copies itself.
> 14. The replacing action of a `COPY` statement shall not introduce a `COPY` statement, a `SOURCE FORMAT` directive, a comment or a blank line.

Comment: I've found the same reference in the 2002 standard, edited the post accordingly.

Comment: You can get around this restriction by using the free standing "REPLACE" directive before/after your copy statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can using COPY REPLACING in a main program to insert a copybook.

You can use COPY REPLACING in a copybook, to copy other copy books into the copybook.

So, yes, nested copy books are allowed. So the COBOL compiler allow this.
They don't occur a lot in practice, but they do occur.

Comment: Interesting, TIL. I'm new to COBOL and mainframes in general, so I'm glad to see questions being asked on here and answered. :)

Comment: There are COBOL old-timers here that can answer questions.  I'm more of a language generalist; most of my knowledge comes from trying to build translation tools for languages... including COBOL.  Unfortunately, this means I get to learn a lot about what makes languages hard to understand or process.

Comment: Ira, this is actually no new information: the question already says "different COBOL compilers allow this - but does any COBOL standard explicit allow/forbit it".

Answer (score 1):

The standard (draft 2010) has 7.2.2.3 13)

The implementation shall support nesting of at least 5 levels, including the first COPY statement in the sequence. The library text being copied shall not cause the processing of a COPY statement that directly or indirectly copies itself.

But 11) 12) and 14) mention restrictions on these nested books not including any REPLACING phrase, or where the replacement includes COPY.  That all makes sense, as a single COPY statement is not meant to be recursive, but can encapsulate other COPY statements during the processing.